# Deleting duplicate records based on certain columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my table, the column `company` will have either A,B,C as its value.

I have multiple `person#` that are duplicates between A,B,C in multiple months and year. The data is c is not the greatest so if there is record that is in C that is either in company A or B i want to delete that record for Company C for that month.

Here is how the columns I am using here are setup

```
 1. [ Person No#], [Company], [Year], [month], and so on
 2. 120       ,    A     ,  2020 ,   January,  ...
 1. 120       ,    B     ,  2020 ,   January, ...
 1. 352       ,    B     ,  2019,    March,  ....
```

I did  the following to try to find out duplicates in multiple companies by it is only showing duplicate records in company C.  example of a row I am getting this:

```
 1. PersNo#,Company,Year,   month,  company, count
 2. 118     C       2019    April   2
```

Code:

```
SELECT
    [Person No#], [Company], [Year], [month], COUNT(*) as [company count]
FROM
    table 1
GROUP BY
    [Person No#], [Company], [Year], [month]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY
    [Person No#], [Company], [month], [Year]
```

What I was trying to see was for example jan 2020 person no# 102 appeared in both companies a & c so their count is > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE t 
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.[Company] = 'C'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tablename 
    WHERE [Person No#] = t.[Person No#] AND [Year] = t.[Year] AND [month] = t.[month]
      AND [Company] <> t.[Company]
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d903abdfb1599496c66d43eddc2cc257).

Comment: @jrj this code deletes all rows with Company = 'C' if there are other rows for the same person, year and number but with different Company. Check the demo.

Comment: thanks for this is there a way to replace the delete with the select to see what will be deleted as i wanted to make sure? i tried replacing it but it wouldnt work in the demo or on sql

Comment: @jrj check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf26acf0f791e1f8fe8c76547e34aa91

Comment: thank you! this worked. question for you.

 before i run this query, how do i delete duplicates records overall. 

so let say if company A,B,and C have any existing duplicate records in general, i want to delete those records then run this query to delete any person in company C with same person # month and date that exist in A or B as done by this query.

Comment: What makes 2 rows duplicates in this case? Which columns must be the same to consider the rows duplicates?

Comment: if every column in a row is the same as another.

so in this case row 1 and 2 are the same in this example:
Row [Person No#], [Company], [Year], [month], ect
1,     12345, A, 2020, Jan, ect
2,     12345, A, 2020, Jan, ect
3,      35635, A, 2020, Jan, ect

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e00a147e8c5308b5a619404788853431

Comment: thanks this works but i get the following error: "View 'cte' is not updatable because the definition contains a UNION operator." i am on sql server 2012 so not sure if thats it?

Comment: tried the following but didnt work:
`delete * from (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY [Person No#], [Company], [Year], [month] 
           ORDER BY (SELECT null)
         ) rn
  FROM tablename
)  

WHERE rn > 1`

Comment: The code works fine in fiddle with SQL Server 2014: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e00a147e8c5308b5a619404788853431 but I can't test it in 2012 because that version is unavailable. The query that you tried is syntactically wrong. Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f476c7ade31ba1612b51532a9b911c8c

Comment: ya i am getting _" Derived table 't' is not updatable because the definition contains a UNION operator._ for the test you tried above.

same issue. with the first query above [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e00a147e8c5308b5a619404788853431]. getting: _View 't' is not updatable because the definition contains a UNION operator._

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table, like an id?

Comment: i am doing view of a union based on company a,b,c with the same columns so no ? but if i was doing a join essentially the primary key would be the person #

Comment: All the queries that I posted work only as they are. I can't tell if they work in different datasets such as unions. So I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[Company]` field from `group by clause`

```
SELECT
        [ Person No#], [Year], [month],  COUNT(*) as [company count]
    FROM
        table 1
GROUP BY
     [ Person No#], [Year], [month]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1 order by  [ Person No#],  [month], [Year]
```

Comment: thanks but how do i delete the duplicate records for month, year person number where if they are in company c and a or b i want to only keep the record for company a or b for that month year and employee number

Comment: do  you've any ID column in your table @jrj

Comment: the person no# is the unique id linked to each person. other than that i dont have an id column

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are a good way to tackle duplicates issues:

```sql
    SELECT
        [Person No#]
      , [Company]
      , [Year]
      , [month]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Person No#],year,month ORDER BY company desc) AS Ranking
    FROM
        table 1
```

Would allow you to delete duplicate records by selecting `WHERE Ranking>1`

Comment: thanks but when i do WHERE Ranking>1 to see whats greater than one it says the column dosnt exist?

Comment: True, `RANKING`is not a valid column name in the actual query but you need to use my suggestion as a subquery like so: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT
        [Person No#]
      , [Company]
      , [Year]
      , [month]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Person No#],year,month ORDER BY company desc) AS Ranking
    FROM
        table 1) as a WHERE RANKING>1`

Comment: thanks this works but how do it delete this? as when i replace select with delete i get an error?

Comment: `DELETE FROM table1 
FROM
 (SELECT         
  [Person No#]  AS PNR
, [Company] AS CMP
, [Year] AS YR
, [month]  AS MO
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Person No#],year,month ORDER BY company desc) AS Ranking     
FROM table1) as a 
WHERE 
  RANKING>1 AND 
  [Person No#]=PNR AND
  [Company]=CMP AND
  [Year]=YR AND
  [month] = MO
`
Though I'd probably like to suggest to add some sort of ID column to your table to make the where condition less costly.